# Paid for sick day, how to proceed?

Tags: salary, united-kingdom, sickness

I was ill one of the days this month, so should have had that days pay deducted but I havent. I received my payslip today. How do I go about a telling my boss?

Unsure how to structure my email to him.

Comment: This depends on your contract and location.  Here in the UK, salaried people get paid, even if they're off sick.  Are you sure you're not entitled to sick pay?

Comment: @snow I too am in the UK. Yes, I've been ill a few other times and have had pay deducted for that day.

Comment: Just confirming, you are salaried?

Comment: @gregory Currie yes

Comment: @codfish555 It is very strange for someone to be salaried but not paid for sick days (or at least a certain number of them). Are you certain that the days you weren't paid were not the mistake?

Comment: Maybe your boss just forgot to tell HR/Payroll, although I agree with @DavidK that its normal (but not mandatory) for salaried employees to get at least a few days sick leave. Don't forget that this is per annum, after which the counter resets. The exact date is company specific, although usually follows either the calendar or tax year (April 6th in the UK). If your company doesn't pay for this, you're entitled to "Statutory Sick Pay", but only after 4 days of absence (See https://www.gov.uk/statutory-sick-pay).

Comment: I don't know what is in your contract, but it is normal in the UK to get paid for sick days.

Comment: Were you sick late in the month, when HR may not have had time to change your pay details before the payroll was processed? There is normally a cut-off date after which changes cannot be made in time and will be applied in the following month instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How do I go about a telling my boss?

First, read your contract and employee handbook and make sure that you are not entitled to be paid for missing the day that you missed.  Next, talk to your boss, either in person on the phone or email.  Let him know that you were absent on X day and that you were paid ( you can present a copy of the payslip ).  Your boss should be able to correct the mistake for you.

You can word your communication with something like this:

> Hello boss.  On day X I was out sick and I noticed on my payslip that pay was not deducted for this day.  According to my contract pay is deducted on the days that I have missed, this has occurred previous times that I have been ill.  Just letting you know.  Thanks.

Comment: @codfish555 You should read your contract and employee handbook first

Comment: @sf02 I wouldn't mention the previous times, but the contract terms!

Comment: Even if you aren't sure what the policy is, this is a good answer. The email can just be reflected to say "Last time you did this, but this time you didn't. Which is correct?"